# Accepted answer is a copy and paste

Tags: discussion

I came across this question on SO, and found that the accepted answer was literally just a copy and paste job. Although the answer is valid, I have seen some answers get down voted for just being either link only or copy or paste such as this.

So my question is, is this valid?

[What is purpose of database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674222/what-is-purpose-of-database-schema)

Comment: This is normal.  It's in 'Rep Farming for Dummies'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is this valid?

Yes, because:

1. it does answer the question, providing enough information in the answer itself (the problem with link-only answers is when you have to go and read the linked content to get the actual answer to the question); and
2. it is very clear that the content was taken from elsewhere, and where that was (the problem with copy-paste answers is when the user presents it as their own work and doesn't appropriately reference it).

Note also that it's a Community Wiki answer, so the author doesn't gain rep from votes on it.

Comment: Won't they still get any badges that the answer is eligible for?

Comment: @JoeW no, the tag badges specify *"non-community wiki answers*"

Comment: I was not referring to the "Tag" badges but badges in general and according to a post on meta stack exchange they do get badges from the post and reputation gained from before it was a community wiki. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @JoeW oh, I see; then, yes! I guess that applies to Nice/Good/Great Answer.